# Starting python script with rc.local

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie

I want to execute a script at startup using rc.local. For this I use the following file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e


/usr/bin/python /public/test.py&
exit 0
```

This testfile should write something into another file, just for test purposes. And not even that works. But if I write something like

```
echo "some test output" >> /public/rc.log
```

everything works fine and I get an additional line.

Later on I want to start a programm measuring all kinds of things. For this it must access GPIO, I2C and W1. I'm sure at the point where rc.local gets started a lot of libaries aren't ready yet to be used. Is there any trigger that tells me that now everything is ready? Something like the documentReady event in Javascript, but on raspbian?

UPDATE:
I also tried crontab, where I did the following

First I typed `crontab -e`
then wrote `@reboot /usr/bin/python /public/cron.py`. In this file I wrote

```
   with open("rc.log", "a") as f:
   f.write("Hello, cronjob\n")
   f.close()
```

But also: Nothing happens.

Comment: Did you use that exact indentation for your Python script, or did it just copy incorrectly? The code used here would cause an `IndentationError`. It might be worth [setting up logging for rc.local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722274/6650102) and including the output to see if anything gets logged.

Comment: `rc.local` is a SysV service. `systemd` init services run asynchronously. The only way to ensure required services are started is to use a  `systemd` service with nominated dependencies.

Comment: yes I have logging file. I log things with the following command: /usr/bin/python /public/main.py >> /public/conOut.log written in rc.local. Surprisingly somethines I get a log result and somethimes I don't. and @Milliways how exactly can I use a 'systemd service with nominated dependencies' this sounds like it would solve all my problems ^^